# Conditional Formatting two sheets and based on drop down value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a work sheet called `Current` and within it a Column `SportsTeam`. The values for `SportsTeam` are populated as a dropdown list.  The values for the dropdown list are in worksheet called `Setup`. In `Setup`I have two columns:

```
Name of team | Team Colour
Warriors     | Cell bkrd color is team colour
Cougars      | Cell bkrd color is team colour
etc.
```

I populate the dropdown in `Current` with the values of the Column `Name Of Team`.

I want that, when a user selects a Team name from the dropdown in worksheet `Current`, that cell background colour changes to the corresponding `Team Colour`.

Answer (score 1):

`Setup` is no help for Conditional formatting from the menu. Select Column `Sports Team` of `Current` and apply **Text is exactly** of:

```
Cougars
```

with formatting of your choice, and add a **Text is exactly** rule for:

```
Warriors
```

with formatting of your choice.

Repeat the same principle for as many teams as you require. Then <kbd>Done</kbd>.